# AutocompleteSupportFragment places .getAddress is null. Is getAddress is deprecated?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am using AutocompleteSupportFragment  in my project

```
AutocompleteSupportFragment places places = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocompleteFragment);
places.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));  
places.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
@Override
public void onPlaceSelected(@NonNull Place place) {
    try {
        if ( location_switch.isChecked() ) {
            if ( place.getName() != null ) {
                destination = place.getName().toString();
                destination = destination.replace(" ", "+");
                if ( Constants.IS_LOGG_ENABLE ) {
                    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Destination Location = " + destination);
                    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", Place ID: " + place.getId());
                    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Address = " + place.getAddress());
                }
                getDirection();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(DriverMainActivity.this, "Error occurred, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(DriverMainActivity.this, "Please change your status to ONLINE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        if(Constants.IS_LOGG_ENABLE){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Perfectly get me place name and id but I need address of that selected place

> Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", Place ID: " +
>   place.getId());

like this, but I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException on this line

> Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Address = " + place.getAddress());

Comment: can you please post the stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered setting the Address in this line `places.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));`   you seem to be setting only the ID and Name and yet you are want to get the address as well which is not set to any value

Comment: I want to get address from place API so, I didn't get

Comment: You can try to request for the address field `Place.Field.ADDRESS` before you use `place.getAddress());` please see documentation for details [link](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/place-details)

Answer (score 0):

alter two sections :

Line 1 of the code snippet shared ,from :
`AutocompleteSupportFragment places places = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)`
to :
`AutocompleteSupportFragment  places = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)`

Line 3 of the code snippet shared ,from :
this:     `places.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));`
to
` places.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME,Place.Field.ADDRESS));

Answer (score -1):

Use **Place.Field.values()** to get all Places values

```
List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.values());
//        List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.ADDRESS);
        Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields).build(this);
        startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
```